# Our Sharepoint list with PowerApp form suddenly stopped working. No updates or changes made. The list displays but you cannot click on an item

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, post

Our SharePoint online list uses a powerapp for creating and editing items. There have been no changes to the app or the list. We get POST 400 errors when debugging.

When the list loads there are also some errors.

"Refused to load the script 'https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/c/ms.shared.analytics.mectrl-3.2.7.gbl.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' "

Any help would be greatly appreciated. We rely heavily on this list as a tool to run our business and it is really hurting us at the moment. Thank you.
I am unfortunately not good with code and need guidance as to where to look?

In addition if we copy a link to a new browser window I get the following error:

"Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property."